# Spring Boot :Logback not picking values from application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I am trying to log the properties mentioned in application.properties using logback.

application.properties 
appName=myservice
logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %appName %-5level - %msg%n %ex

tried the above pattern and got the below output :

13:10:52.193 [main] [%PARSER_ERROR[appName]]DEBUG - Execution of method runends : return value -> null

expected out is :

13:10:52.193 [main] [myservice]DEBUG - Execution of method runends : return value -> null

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `property` in the pattern

> logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %property{KEY}
>   %-5level - %msg%n %ex

For this, you have to add KEY in VM argument like `-DKEY=myservice`.

11:15:23.474 [main] myservice INFO  - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

Comment: I cannot do that as I am developing a logging utility and consuming application needs to have the appName in its application.properties/yml